# Display category description (one time) in a list of product in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web

i have a list in the model of one sale, and i display all products in it, but, now i need to display the category description, (one time) for each products from the seame category, how can be done?

```
Product          Quantity          Price

*Licors (This is the category)
Brugal           1                 500
Barcelo          15                700

*Fruits (This is the category)
Apple            1                 25
Banana           3                 5
```

what i need to show is the description `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.Category.Description)` on (up) the product name
This is my code

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="center"></th>
      <th>Serv./Prod.</th>
      <th class="center">Cant.</th>
      <th class="right">Precio</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>                  
 @foreach (var item in Model.SalesDetails.OrderBy(p=>p.Product.CategoryId))
  {
    <tr>
      <td class="center"></td>
      <td class="left">   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.Name)</td>
      <td class="right">     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)</td>
      <td class="center">   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.SellPrice)</td>
    </tr>
}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: where is the description?

Comment: is it inside foreach?

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI Why is your name shouting at me?

Comment: @FrankerZ sorry sir i could not undertand what do you mean

Comment: Product.CategoryId have a Product.Category.Description

Comment: i think he means upper case is a bit like shouting ie your username :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is my example. Let me know if you want more details.

```
@{    
list = list.OrderBy(p => p.id).ToList();
}

<table>
@foreach (var item in list)
{
    <tr>
        <td class="center"></td>
        <td class="left">   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.product)</td>
        <td class="right">     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.quantity)</td>
        <td class="center">   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for the sample, but in this case, it dont work, because your sample it the same that im doing on this part var item in Model.SalesDetails.OrderBy(p=>p.Product.CategoryId)

Comment: It works in my computer. You may have some other mistakes. Please give more details if you need help ;)

Comment: Emmm, let me be more explicit, it works, but, is the same than i have, on my post, so, it works, but dont do what i need